# Pass parameter from link function to the template in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have simple directive and I want access to the variable in link function in the template. how i can achieve that?

**My directive :**

```
app.directive("hello", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: '<div> '+str+' <div/>'
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var str = "hello";
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a code on codepen: [demo](http://codepen.io/sajadabedi/pen/KMVpLM?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the variable in the scope and they will be available in the template

```
scope.str = "hello";
```

and your template should use the angular expression

```
template: '<div>{{str}}<div/>',
```

so your directive will be like

```
app.directive("hello", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: '<div>{{str}}<div/>',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.str = "hello";
    }
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

If you want to bind html use [ngbindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Please find the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4VbF8vXT2bTklz2Rs5YF?p=preview)

Comment: It's work but instead of use `'<div> '+str+' <div/>'` i use `'<div> {{str}} <div/>'`

Comment: hi i have similar situation but instead of string i need to pass an html string  <h1>hi<h1/> , how can i achieve that , i f you can please update your plnkr. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Aji Please look at  the link i.e. ngBindHtml. At this page you will get the exact example of what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple ways  i need to explain you here so please consider both side changes need i mean you want to send variable from directive call

```
<html ng-app="app">
<body>
  <hello data-str="'I am don'"></hello>
</body>
</html>
```

here  data-str  means there  str is variable which having  text "I am don"  thats it

now

```
angular.module("app", []);

angular.module("app").directive("hello", function() {
  return {
    scope:{
      str:"="
    },
    restrict: "E",
    template: '<div>{{linkVar}}{{str}}<div/>',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
     scope.linkVar = 'It works!' 
      console.log(scope.str);
    }
  }
});
```

Here

you can see  this in directive object added by me

```
 scope:{
          str:"="
        },
```

here we decide that  "str" will be provided when  directive calls in html like this   instead of  only this  Please take care

now

```
scope.linkVar = 'It works!'
```

this is most important thing you should see   scope.linkVar  means you had just javascript variable with name  str = "hello";  this is not angular way so angular will not update its all references. I mean when you use in templates.

now hope it clear and let me know if yes.
Have a great time

## khajaamin

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'this'

```
app.directive("hello", function() {
  return {
    this.str = '';
    restrict: "E",
    template: '<div> '+this.str+' <div/>'
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
      this.str = "hello";
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: When I use `this` keyword print `undefined ` instead of hello !